# Why were the Middle Ages called the Dark Ages?

Tags: grid-deduction, mazes, humor

You find yourself trapped in a room, with only one door to escape, and an important question to answer. You are standing on the tile marked with yellow:

[image: room with startposition and exit door]

**How to get to the door is the main problem.** You may only move exactly as many tiles as the number you are standing on, in any direction. You cannot go through a wall, and you have to reach exactly the tile the door is on. To explain this visually, if you are standing on the 2 marked below, then you could move either to the 1, 5, 4 or 3.

[image: movement explanation]

Additionally, you have found a cheat sheet, which may lead to the final answer. Unfortunately however, you spilled some coffee on it, which makes some of it impossible to read:

[image: cheat sheet with a lot of coffee covering it]

---

Text only:

```
    4 7 1 2 6 2 2 3 1
    6 2 3 3 1 7 6 2 1
    5 5 2 5 7 4 2 5 3
    1 4 5 6 3 3 2 5 1
    4 4 4 3 7 2 2 3 2
    2 5 5 2 2 1 7 1 2
    2 7 2 3 6 7 2 1 3
X 4 2 7 1 5 1 2 3 4 7
    4 2 4 5 1 2 4 5 1
    6 1 2 6 7 3 1 2 5
    4 2 5 4 7 4 3 2*5*
    1 6 1 5 5 3 3 1 2
    6 2 4 1 6 1 4 1 6
    6 5 5 1 1 3 4 2 3
    2 3 2 1 3 1 6 1 2
    4 4 1 6 4 2 1 2 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve maze to get path

> use cheat sheet to decipher path with steps + direction.

Solution to riddle

> Too Many Knights

Explanation

> There are 28 cells in the cheat sheet and there two visibly empty, so 26 filled slots. Based on the shown Q,U,Y & P; we assume it lists the alphabet A, B, C, ... from Left to Right, Top to Bottom, as an English book. The left is numbered 1-7 and the top is U, ??, L, D. We assume the missing top letter is R indicating the 4 directions. We then use our moves (5 spots Down) as a coordinate (5D) and look up the letter "T". Once the maze is solved, you can convert the moves into letters. I tested moves with letters and kept track until a valid phrase came out that also solved the maze.

Comment: I have the maze solved but I do not know how to spoiler tag an image :)

Comment: Post it anyway and someone passing by can help you :)

Comment: Can you explain your solution some more?

Comment: There are 28 cells in the cheat sheet and there two visibly empty, so 26 filled slots. Based on the shown Q,U,Y & P; we assume it lists the alphabet A, B, C, ... from Left to Right, Top to Bottom, as an English book. The left is numbered 1-7 and the top is U, ??, L, D. We assume the missing top letter is R indicating the 4 directions. We then use our moves (5 spots Down) as a coordinate (5D) and look up the letter "T". Once the maze is solved, you can convert the moves into letters. I tested moves with letters and kept track until a valid phrase came out that also solved the maze.

Comment: Answers should come with explanations in the answer, not in the comments - please Edit your answer to add this explanation to it! And welcome to Puzzling!

Comment: Although the answer is correct, but could you please add screenshots to your answer of the final maze? And maybe of the final cheat sheet as well? That would make this answer much more complete, more interesting, and easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

If Rob's solution is the intended one, I have found an unintended solution to the maze, which does not lead to a solution to the title question.

The sequence I found is:

> L5, U4, L3, D2, R4, U1, R1, D2, L3, L2, U6, U1, D5, L2

Illustrated:

> [image: Traversal above of the path in the puzzle image]

The method I used to find this was to

> Start at the door and count to find what tiles could reach it, then count from those tiles to find out what tiles could reach those - essentially flood-filling the maze in reverse until I found the start square.

Comment: Arrgh, I have done my best to make this puzzle unique, but you have found one exception. Well done! (And sorry for that) Just out of curiousity, what would be the final sentence this way? There is a one in a billion chance that it produces a nice sentence like 'this is a red herring' ;)

Comment: The problem I have overlooked is the R4. That one move shouldn't be possible. The 4 I had marked as 'accessible from start' and the destination 1 I had marked as 'end is accessible from that one'. After that R4 move, you could have found a simpler solution by continuing R4 U1 L1 L5.

Comment: If that specific 1 was instead a 4, there was a unique solution...

Comment: @Lezzup - The message is SMKHNABHKGUATG, which I could probably turn into a message by the magic of apophenia if I tried, but doesn't mean anything naturally. The shorter solution you advised gives SMKHNACS.

Comment: Well, that SMKHNACS of coincidence...